# Footer and <hr> not shown after contact form

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, contact-form

So everything looks fine on the contact form, but when i try to add an `<hr>`after or some line breaks, nothing registers. My footer is still there, though. I'm not sure what the problem is.

```
<!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="inner contact">
        <!-- Form Area -->
        <div class="contact-form">
            <!-- Form -->
            <form id="contact-us" method="post" action="#">
                <!-- Left Inputs -->
                <div class="col-xs-6 wow animated slideInLeft" data-wow-delay=".5s">
                    <!-- Name -->
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required="required" class="form" placeholder="Name" />
                    <!-- Email -->
                        <input type="email" name="mail" id="mail" required="required" class="form" placeholder="Email" />
                    <!-- Subject -->
                        <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" required="required" class="form" placeholder="Subject" />
                </div>
                <!-- End Left Inputs -->

              <!-- Right Inputs -->
                <div class="col-xs-6 wow animated slideInRight" data-wow-delay=".5s">
                    <!-- Message -->
                        <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form textarea"  placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                </div>
              <!-- End Right Inputs -->
              <!-- Bottom Submit -->
                    <div class="relative fullwidth col-xs-12">
                    <!-- Send Button -->
                        <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="form-btn semibold">Send Message</button> 
                    </div>
              <!-- End Bottom Submit -->
              <!-- Clear -->
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </form>
            </div>
        <!-- End Contact Form Area -->
        </div>


        <hr>

<!-- Footer -->
<div class="footer">
    <p>© 2016 Junebug Mixology | All Rights Reserved</p>
</div>

</div>
<!-- /.container -->
```

Comment: Should the footer div be inside the container?

Comment: Try adding `<div class="clearfix"></div> ` before <hr>

Comment: Thanks, Adrian. The clearfix fixed it!